# How can I embed a terminal in Tkinter GUI to execute python scripts

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

I am trying to make a Python IDE which edits python scripts and executes them and show the output in the GUI itself. I have made the GUI in tkinter. For showing the outputs, I am using `os.system("python myscript.py &> output.txt")` and displaying the output.txt file in the GUI. Now i am facing issues in raw_input() function as the execution stops and output.txt isn't generated, also i can't send values to the terminal from the GUI when raw_input() is waiting. I am thinking of embedding a terminal in the GUI. How can i do that? How can i execute python scripts in that terminal and give inputs and get outputs?